# Content Editable .text() will keep old value but show new value on DOM

Tags: javascript, meteor, contenteditable

I'm trying to make inline-editing by my own.

I'm using meteor.

Here is my structure.

```
<p id="pEdit" contentEditable="true">{{initialContent}}</p>
```

When I edit the content, on the page, it will show the new value.

But when I click the update button that I have,
it will return `old value + new value`.

For example, If i had `This is my info`. And edited it to `This is new`, on the page it will show `This is new`.

But if I upload, or `console.log($('p#pEdit').text()`, I will get, `This is my infoThis is new`.

I'm grabbing the value by `$('p#pEdit').text()` before inserting into the database.

**Update1** Details

Answer (score 0):

### Answer on own post

Apparently this is a meteor.blaze problem.

Here is the thread I found. There are temporary workarounds, but it's a meteor native problem.

I hope anyone who stumbles across the same problem finds this link.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1964